# airflow db init could not find table 'ab_role' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, mysql-python

Airflow 2.4.3

I dropped and created a new database and issued airflow db init
getting the fllowing error as some few tables are missing,

How can I over come this error
[2022-11-29 14:46:48,449] {migration.py:204} INFO - Context impl MySQLImpl.
[2022-11-29 14:46:48,450] {migration.py:207} INFO - Will assume non-transactional DDL.
.....
...
....

```
 File "/opt/airflow_test/az/airflow_env/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 2373, in column
    raise exc.NoReferencedTableError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'ab_permission_view_role.role_id' could not find table 'ab_role' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

### getting error in starting the airflow webserver

```
'ab_permission_view_role.permission_view_id' could not find table 'ab_permission_view'
```

Comment: airflow info -- to check the right airflow.cfg file path. I had issues with mysql db user and file path and grant priveleges.

Comment: export AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN="postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/my_database?options=-csearch_path%3Dairflow"
export AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_SCHEMA="airflow"

Answer (score 2):

The causes of the error were very diverse. I encountered this error while migrating an instance from GCP cloud. I've tried many things, but I'll write down what I remember.

1. In the database set in the airflow.cfg file, first check if there is a foreign key with that table.
2. If it already exists, it seems to be a sqlalchemy version conflict issue. Airflow 2.5.1 in 1.4.46 has been confirmed to work normally. (Other versions generate errors)

   pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.46
3. Restart.

thank you